# Updating multiple columns in pandas dataframe with function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I've tried searching this on Stack Overflow but don't seem to be able to find the same scenario. I'm trying to update multiple columns in my pandas dataframe in one line of code with same function. I can update each column individually, but want the function to update multiple columns simultaneously.

The function is basic:

```
binary_values = lambda x: 0 if x == -99 else 1
```

I know I can assign scalar values to sections of the dataframe like this:

```
df.ix[:,22:26] = 1
```

I'm trying to do something like below:

```
df.ix[:,22:26] = df.ix[:,22:26].apply(binary_values)
```

...but it throws up ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index..')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lambda` function is not vectorized, you need `applymap` to apply it to each element of your data frame:

```
df.iloc[:,22:26] = df.iloc[:,22:26].applymap(binary_values)
```

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[1,2,3,-99,5,3],
    "B":[2,3,5,2,-99,2],
    "C":[-99,3,2,1,4,5]
})

binary_values = lambda x: 0 if x == -99 else 1
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(binary_values)

df

#   A   B   C
#0  1   1   0
#1  2   1   1
#2  3   1   1
#3  -99 1   1
#4  5   0   1
#5  3   1   1
```

A simpler (vectorized) option is check the equality and then convert the data type to int:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].ne(-99).astype(int)

df
#   A   B   C
#0  1   1   0
#1  2   1   1
#2  3   1   1
#3  -99 1   1
#4  5   0   1
#5  3   1   1
```